# (Android) better to store a single table of data in sqlite or as a text file?

Tags: android, sql, parsing, local-storage, text-parsing

I've a single data table, fully structured, that my app will require.

It consists of a few thousand rows, three columns separated by spaces (in the text file I load from), and I need these to have specific priority assigned to them.

That priority is stored as an int and will be modified.
I considered keeping the whole thing in memory (it's fairly short strings), and simply writing to text with updated int values at the end of a session. An alternative approach would be a single sqlite table that I update as the app functions.

I'm sure it's fine either way, but just out of curiosity, which would perform worse, reading/writing to sql table or text parsing?

Comment: Question is not precise enought. "fast" depends on many things and may be subjective. And it depends on what you need to do with the data. If you only need to access first/last items, a queue should even be better in term of memory usage... But if you may have random access, or access in order, or... there are too many parameters to answer the question correctly.

Comment: I'd go for a database table. So to have the ability of searching, averaging, grouping, uèdating, inserting, deleting, ... without having to write all the routines to do that. And without the need of keeping in memory all the data at once.

Comment: @Feuby better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Rotwand, you should go for a database just for the whole abilities provided. Text parsing may be faster only if you only access to first/last rows, or maybe select data sequentialy in the order.
In other cases, trying to optimize text parsing will lead you to something equivalent to database, thus, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Text parsing (or serialization) may also be an option if you have specific needs (complex object structures, very few objects, ...) but database should still be a good thing at least to have more access options.

Comment: Thanks, accepting as answer.

I really can't think of a way to make it less broad than it already is.